# Error: assignment of member '' in read-only object

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, parâmetros

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Ecoponto{
  int codigo;
  int contentores[3];
  char *cidade;
  char *rua;
  int nporta;
}ecoponto;



int insereEcoponto (const struct Ecoponto ecoponto[],int tam,int pos,int codigo,int porta,char* cidade,char* rua){



for(pos=0;pos<tam;pos++){
    if(ecoponto[pos].codigo == codigo){
        return 0;
    }
}




if(pos<tam){
    ecoponto[pos].codigo = codigo;
    ecoponto[pos].nporta = porta;
    ecoponto[pos].cidade = cidade;
    ecoponto[pos].rua= rua;
    ecoponto[pos].contentores[0] = 0;
    ecoponto[pos].contentores[1] = 0;
    ecoponto[pos].contentores[2] = 0;
}else{
    printf("Vetor cheio.\n");
    return 0;
}

}
```

Erros:

```
main.c:41:30: error: assignment of member 'codigo' in read-only object
     ecoponto[pos].codigo = codigo;
                          ^
main.c:42:30: error: assignment of member 'nporta' in read-only object
     ecoponto[pos].nporta = porta;
                          ^
main.c:43:30: error: assignment of member 'cidade' in read-only object
     ecoponto[pos].cidade = cidade;
                          ^
main.c:44:26: error: assignment of member 'rua' in read-only object
     ecoponto[pos].rua= rua;
                      ^
main.c:45:38: error: assignment of read-only location '(ecoponto + (sizetype)((long unsigned int)pos * 40ul))->contentores[0]'
     ecoponto[pos].contentores[0] = 0;
                                  ^
main.c:46:38: error: assignment of read-only location '(ecoponto + (sizetype)((long unsigned int)pos * 40ul))->contentores[1]'
     ecoponto[pos].contentores[1] = 0;
                                  ^
main.c:47:38: error: assignment of read-only location '(ecoponto + (sizetype)((long unsigned int)pos * 40ul))->contentores[2]'
     ecoponto[pos].contentores[2] = 0;
                                  ^
```

Por que é que tenho esses erros não estou a perceber. Sei que tem a ver com `ecoponto[pos].""=""` mas não estou a ver o porquê.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você declarou o parâmetro como `const` então não pode modificá-lo. Se a intenção é modificar não deve usar este modificador. Pode ter outros problemas no código, mas esses erros em específico são gerados por isso.

Já que criou um tipo com `typedef`, poderia ter usado ele na declaração do parâmetro. Assim funciona, mas é um desperdício. Poderia ter declarado `ecoponto ecoponto[]`. Ou melhor ainda, inverte os nomes no `typedef`, idealmente os nomes de tipos devem ser em maiúsculo para evitar confusão com nome de variável, aí o tipo seria `Ecoponto`.

Comment: ALias -  não está criando "ecoponto" como um tipo no typedef, e depois usano "ecoponto" como nome de variável?

Comment: @jsbueno também. Editado. Obrigado por lembrar.